# About generated $\sigma$-algebras (proof verification).

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

It would be really helpful if anyone would browse through this and tell me if my solution is ok. Here is the question:

> 1. Let $C \subset 2^X$ be a collection of subsets. Show that for every $K \in \sigma(C)$ there exists a sequence $(C_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \subset C$ satisfying $K \in \sigma(\{C_1,C_2, \dots\})$.

My solution is as follows:

Let $A = \displaystyle \bigcup_{E \in \mathscr{N}} \sigma(E)$ where $\mathscr{N} \subset C$ is the subset of all countable subcollections of $C$.

let $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \subset A$. It follows that $a_i \in \sigma(M_i)$ for some countable subcollection $M_i \subset C$. Clearly $\bigcup_{i \in N} M_i \in \mathscr{N}$ and so $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} a_i \in \sigma(\bigcup_{i \in N} M_i) \subset A$. Therefore $A$ is closed under countable unions. Closeness to complements is evident.

$\implies$ $A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Clearly $C \subset A$ and $A \subset \sigma(C)$ but $\sigma(C)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $C$ so $\sigma(C)=A$. qed.

Comment: You are asked to show that given a set $A$ which belongs to $\sigma(C)$ there exists a sequence $C_i$ satisfying the given condition. (Note that $A$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra, it is a set). You are not allowed to choose a particular $A.$ Also, I suppose that it should be $C_i\ne C,$ since in other case the solution is trivial.

Comment: @mfl The notation is a bit confusing. It would have been better if $\mathcal A$ had been chosen for the occurrence of $A$ after the words "My solution is as follows: Let..."

Comment: I fixed the notation problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of your proof is okay (and very nice).

Note: in your proof you write $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}M_{i}\subset\mathcal{N}$.

That should be changed into $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}M_{i}\in\mathcal{N}$.

Comment: Thanks, i guess i'll except your answer and edit to fix that typo.

Comment: You are welcome. Final remark: the countable intersections can be left out. Countable unions and complements are enough by proving that it is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Yeah, I know, just wasn't confident enough to leave it out. Thanks again.